# Check if app's today widget is installed

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, today-extension

How to check if a Today Widget that comes with the app is installed or not...

If the user doesn't have the widget installed, i would like to present him a intro how to install it

Comment: share data between app and today widget: http://www.glimsoft.com/06/28/ios-8-today-extension-tutorial/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conceptually, have your iOS app check for the presence of some flag that's only added once the Today extension is activated.

`NSUserDefaults` is a fine way to accomplish this — you'll need to [use App Groups](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH4-SW19) to accomplish data sharing.

Comment: but there is no way to know, once the widget has been uninstalled :(

Comment: You can store a timestamp in the user defaults so that the widget sends a heartbeat signal.